# Cannot display Dialog box after clicking the flex table cell in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, dialog

This this the class of my dialog box:

```
public class Question extends DialogBox { 
    public Question(int row, FlexTable flex) {
        super (true);
        setText( "Choose Action");
        String outputString = flex.getWidget(row, 0).toString();
        VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
        panel.add(new Label ("" + outputString));
        panel.add(new Button( "edit")); 
        this.setWidget(panel);
    }
}
```

And this is the way I create an instance of my box after clicking at some row in flex table, but the problem is that I get nothing after, no impact after clicking any row.

```
flex.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick (ClickEvent event){
        int rowlndex = flex.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
        // Window.alеrt("Row Clicked " + rowlndex); --- Works Properly
        Question que = new Question(rowlndex, flex);
        que.center();
        que.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browser's console? Are you sure that every cell  contains `Widget` and not simple text for example? In such situation  `flex.getWidget(row, 0)` would be null and calling `toString()` on null will crush. Is there always only one column?

Comment: Ty a lot, there was a simple text up in my table, so much appreciate!